# Launch a SHELL script, connect to Splunk and show the results

Tags: shell, splunk

I'm such a noob, with Shell and Splunk, just you to know.

I need to launch a shell script in my computer, connect to Splunk and get the results based on a search. The result will be only 1 or 2 numbers, im just trying to get some summary of capacity.

This is my sh code for the moment:

```
user="user"
pass="pass"

search='search index="*big search text*'

curl -u $user:$pass -k https://192.168.x.x:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="$search"
```

I tried to use a Curl command but I have several problems, starting that I don't know the IP address of the Splunk instance... How to check it? I just connect to a website to check the Splunk results.

Please, any help will be apreciated.
Have a good day

Comment: "Connect to a website" -- that hostname part of the URI from that website will be something that resolves to an IP address. If it's the same service offering the web interface as the `/services/search/jobs` API, you can just plug in the same name you use in a browser.

Comment: BTW, `curl -u "$user:$pass"` should have double quotes around the expansions. I don't know if your search is correct quoting-wise (often, using literal rather than syntactic quotes is a bug-smell, but it's not clear whether that's the case here; I'd need to see an example of a valid/working search to compare it to).

Comment: Thanks mate. I use the url of the browser and I receive a big error message, starting with: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- 
    This is a static HTML string template to render errors.  To edit this
    template, see appserver/mrsparkle/lib/error.py. 
-->

Comment: This might be a place where someone who knows Splunk might be better suited -- to answer but at least some competing services need an appropriate header (`Content-Type: application/json` or such) to request machine-readable content.

Comment: Are you sure that DOCTYPE response was an error?  Even non-error responses start with that text.  The actual message should be near the end.

Comment: Have you considered using Python for this task? There is a [Splunk Python SDK](https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/python/sdk-python/) that could handle a lot of the leg-work for you. Seeing as you are a seemingly quite new to these concepts and that Bash (shell scripting) is generally quite limited when it comes to integrating with third party services you are probably going to struggle with the complexities of Splunk's search mechanism using a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

The `services/search/jobs` endpoint launches a new search and returns a search ID.  Use the `services/search/jobs/{search ID}` endpoint to get the status of the job.  Then use the `services/search/v2/jobs/{search ID}/results` or `services/search/v2/jobs/export` endpoint to get the results.

The endpoints are documented at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.4/RESTREF/RESTsearch